# Difficulty in solving differentiation of Acosx/3.

Tags: derivatives

For the differentiation of $a\frac{ \cos x}{3}$ , I get $\frac{1}{3}\frac {\sin x}{3}$

But in answer they showed a as well in my textbook.Why is $a$ not differentiated?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Probably $a$ is a constant.

Comment: Check the rules of differentiation. You will see that $D(k\cdot f(x))=kDf(x)$, where $D$ is the differentiation operator (with respect to $x$, in this case). In other words, constants are not differentiated.

Comment: @MattiP. Why have you written constants are not differentiated whereas Mr.Gae S has done it.

Comment: Well, what I ultimately mean is that the **derivative of a constant is zero**, as demonstrated in Gae's post. The effect that this has, is that the constant can be moved in front of the differentiation.

Comment: Ok.I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that it *has been* differentiated: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[a\frac{\cos x}3\right]=\frac{\cos x}{3}\frac{d}{dx}[a]+a\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\cos x}{3}\right]=0\cdot \frac{\cos x}{3}+a\cdot\left(-\frac{\sin x}3\right)=-\frac{ a\sin x}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you.I want to know then why is Matti.P saying constant are not differentiated.

Comment: @user277768 Ask him.

Comment: I think you have forgotten 1/3 another to multiply in your answer. @Gae.S.

Comment: Like I have written , just include a.

Comment: @user277768 No, I'm right: the derivative of $\frac{\cos x}3$ is $-\frac{\sin x}3$.

Comment: What if it is $sin \frac{x}{3}$@Gae.S.

Comment: @user277768 Then I guess I need to learn how to read. I'll come back to you in 12 to 18 years.